# code java inside javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I´m trying put code java inside alert javascript with:

```
try
{
  table(out, Integer.parseInt(num));
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
   %>
   <script language="javascript" >
     alert("Error." + <%= e.getMessage() %>);
   </script>
   <%
}
```

but don´t work

Comment: do you have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with quotes. Try this:

```
%>
    <script language="javascript" >
        alert("Error. <%= e.getMessage() %>");
    </script>
<%
```

Comment: Way to make the most out of a bad question.

Comment: Thanks dfsq now work fine and sorry Seth and company sorry but I'm not as smart as you

Answer (score 1):

It will not because
Javascript runs on client side, meaning it is run by the user's browser while Java runs server. 
In order for the client side javascript to interact with the backend Java, you need to make a request to the server.